# Django complex query with page load slow

Tags: python, django

I have a quiz application made with Django. I am basically loading a pretty complex query. What I am basically doing is creating a new exam with this logic:

1. Fetch the question from the question bank (the `Question` model)
2. I get a certain questions number from each subject and I use them to create a `QuestionDraft` so I can store and save each student result.
3. Each `QuestionDraft` has the `AnswerDraft` which I use for storing the user answered questions (each `AnswerDraft` is basically a carbon copy of the question bank `Answer`).

While I wanna load a 50-question-test everything works pretty fine but when I want to load more than that amount of question, the page is loading extremely slow.
I would like to know if, based on the models and the code I post down below, there is any way to improve the efficiency of the queries and/or the loading time.

models.py

```
class QuestionSubject(models.Model):
    quiz_course = models.ForeignKey(QuizTheoryCourse, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    exam_questions_num = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Question(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=7,
                          default=generate_question_id,
                          unique=True,
                          primary_key=True,
                          editable=False)
    question_subject = models.ForeignKey(
        QuestionSubject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    mark = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    question_bank_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    question_topic = models.ForeignKey(
        QuestionTopic, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    is_correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class QuizProfile(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=7,
                          default=generate_question_id,
                          unique=True,
                          primary_key=True,
                          editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(
        QuestionSubject, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    total_score = models.DecimalField(default=0,
                                      decimal_places=2,
                                      max_digits=5)
    quiz_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=255, choices=quiz_type, blank=True, null=True)
    right_answer = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    is_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_assigned = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True, default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username + ' ' + self.id

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created_at',)


class QuestionDraft(models.Model):
    quiz_profile = models.ForeignKey(QuizProfile,
                                     on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                     blank=True,
                                     null=True)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question,
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                 blank=True,
                                 null=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    is_answered = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_correct = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.quiz_profile) + ' ' + str(self.question)


class AnswerDraft(models.Model):
    quiz_profile = models.ForeignKey(QuizProfile,
                                     on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                     blank=True,
                                     null=True)
    question_draft = models.ForeignKey(QuestionDraft, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               null=True,
                               blank=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    is_answered = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.quiz_profile) + ' ' + str(self.answer)


class QuizDraft(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=7,
                          default=generate_question_id,
                          unique=True,
                          primary_key=True,
                          editable=False)
    quiz_profile = models.ForeignKey(QuizProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question_draft = models.ForeignKey(QuestionDraft,
                                       on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                       blank=True,
                                       null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.quiz_profile)
```

views.py

```
def ppl_exam_generator_util(request, subjects):
    question_list = [Question.objects.filter(question_subject=subject).order_by(
        '?')[:int(subject.exam_questions_num)]for subject in subjects]
    quiz_profile = QuizProfile(
        user=request.user, quiz_type='ppl_exam')
    quiz_profile.save()
    for ques in question_list:
        for q in ques:
            question = Question.objects.get(id=q.id)
            quiz_attempt = QuizAttempt(quiz_profile=quiz_profile,
                                       question=question)
            quiz_attempt.save()
            question_draft = QuestionDraft(
                question=question, text=question.text, quiz_profile=quiz_profile)
            question_draft.save()
            quiz_draft = QuizDraft(
                quiz_profile=quiz_profile, question_draft=question_draft)
            quiz_draft.save()
            answers = Answer.objects.filter(question__id=question.id)
            shuffle(list(answers))
            for ans in answers:
                draft_answer = AnswerDraft(
                    question_draft=question_draft, answer=ans, text=ans.text, quiz_profile=quiz_profile)
                draft_answer.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('quiz:new_ppl_exam', kwargs={'pk': quiz_profile.id}))
```

I tried also with the `connection.queries` tool Django provides, but each query is pretty fast. I don't know if it's a problem with the nested forloop or something else.

Comment: You're loading more than 50 questions to a single page?  Perhaps you should adopt a strategy of loading the first few questions immediately, then loading the rest in the background.  That way, the user won't see it.

Comment: I am loading and paginating them. I have 1 question displayed, the others are fetched with a click by the user. I am using bootstrap tabs to show them one at a time to the user